# How to change the Selenium IDE file extension (.side file into java file) while saving the project

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide

Currently, am I using the Selenium IDE in the Chrome. My projects are saving in the form of `.side` extension. Is there is any way to change this file as java file for selenium web driver.

Comment: Have you Googled your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19358183/how-to-convert-commands-recorded-in-selenium-ide-to-java

Comment: @AlexeyR. That version of Selenium IDE is not supported anymore.

Answer (score 4):

The ["**NEW**" Selenium IDE](https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/) does not support exports to other languages currently, it is still work in progress, see the github issue: https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium-ide/issues/592

You could use the new command-line runner to run the `.side` files: https://www.seleniumhq.org/selenium-ide/docs/en/introduction/command-line-runner/

**Alternative**:

> Katalon Automation Recorder was developed to support users who no
>   longer be able to record and playback automation tests using the
>   obsolete Selenium IDE or users of popular open source frameworks
>   looking for a handy recorder.
>
> https://www.utest.com/articles/katalon-automation-recorderpowerful-selenium-ide-to-record-debug-play-tests-in-any-browser

[Katalon Recorder](https://www.katalon.com/resources-center/blog/katalon-automation-recorder/) looks a lot like the Selenium IDE, works in Chrome and exports to Java. Click [here for the Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/katalon-recorder/ljdobmomdgdljniojadhoplhkpialdid?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon).

**History of Selenium IDE**:

> On August 8, 2017, Firefox released version 55.0, and Selenium IDE
>   officially died.
>
> From Firefox 55 onwards, Selenium IDE no longer worked.
>
> ...
>
> So in effect, IDE was dead until Applitools came along to resurrect it.

Read about the history and rewrite of Selenium IDE here: https://www.joecolantonio.com/selenium-ide/